# Accessibility inspector freeze when try to inspect element

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode11, macos-catalina

I have a problem when using an accessibility inspector. I updated to a new macOS Catalina and official Xcode 11. When I use an accessibility inspector with Simulator iOS 13 and inspector freezes. If I want to continue to inspect something I must restart the inspector but it never can inspect Simulator iOS 13. Is there an issue as know issue with new macOS Catalina. I haven't a problem with macOS Mojave and Xcode 11(iOS 13).

Can someone help me?

Comment: Same issue if anyone face same issue and found any solution for this please help me.